# How would a world where electronics are organically based differ from ours?

Tags: technology, science-fiction, alternate-worlds, computers

I'm building a Retrofuture space fantasy setting.

Some relevant information on that can be found [here...](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/137114/how-must-computers-telecommunication-deviate-from-reality-for-a-retrofuturistic)

One of the core aspects to me of the retro sci-fi aesthetic is its hardware focused nature. I wanted a setting of **Gearheads** not **Codemonkeys**, as well just wanting to be weird.

So I decided that due to the nature of the "eldritch living crystal" that are at the heart of the setting's appliances and devices, the components possessed certain organic properties.

- In a sense all devices in the setting are wetware.

Sensory organs don't need to be programed to sense, nor do legs need to be programed walk, or hands to grasp walk; their functionality is a natural part of them in encoded in their genes.

Genes could be thought of as the firmware of biological systems, they are also difficult and potentially dangerous to change.

That gene driven nature is the organic property that electronic components in the setting possess.

They are not general purpose: their functionality is defined during their creation, and can only be altered by mutation, a slow and potentially damaging process.

What are "some" of this premise's consequences?

I've been able to think of four...

1. Devices are more task oriented than general purpose, almost like the analog electronic computers of yesteryear.
2. Electronics are much more expensive, since they require a lot of specific parts/organs.
3. Programmers and IT-Technicians are closer to mechanic/surgeons.
4. The production and programing of electronic parts is akin Agriculture/Horticulture.

What other big changes can you think of?

Comment: I am afraid that asking for the consequences of something is a tad too broad. Basically it is a potentially endless list.

Comment: @L.Dutch I know what I'm looking for, the four things that I've already figured out are an indication of my line of reasoning.

Comment: We are not in your mind, unless you put explicitly what you are looking for in your question we cannot read it.

Comment: William Hanna and Joseph Barbera made a multi-season documentary series based on the life of [two families living in this world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flintstones).

Comment: @L.Dutch the end of the question states what I'm looking.

Comment: @AlexP why are you being so snippy.

Comment: That's exactly the issue. First of all, "big changes" is entirely subjective. Second, how are you going to pick between Anna telling you "oh, a big change is thing A" and Brad telling you "nah, a big change is thing B"?